# Is it legal to install 3 prong outlet without ground in the State of Georgia?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I just found out the apartment that I am renting have 3 prong outlets without being grounded. Is this legal in GA?

/update

Attached photo

[image]

/update2

I just tested the bottom-center ground terminal and top-right terminal. My DMM reads 86VAC instead of 124VAC. So it looks like the ground is indeed connected, but there is a leak somewhere. My building technician came and said I dont' have to worry about it because the 3rd prong is just there to add extra support for extra heavy power cords and refused to talk to me more on this issue.

[image]

Comment: Are there stickers "GFCI protected" or "No Equipment Ground" on the outlet?

Comment: Or did someone hook them up to a GFCI but forget to put the stickers on?

Comment: "GFCI protected" are the ones I see on the washrooms correct? If so, nope, they are not GFCI protected. Also there is no sticker whatsoever. Just a bunch of outlets with 3 prongs.

Comment: Check the service panel breakers. They could be GFCI. If so they will have a test button like the more common ones in bathrooms

Comment: I see. I will check the panel. In the meanwhile, I do feel electricity when I touch my computer when it's plugged into one of those un-grounded outlets...

Comment: @Stanwood can you check the photo above?

Comment: We haven't asked what you have done to confirm there is no ground. For example, did you plug in one of those outlet testers with 3 lights on it and it reported back an open ground? Have you opened up an outlet and find no green/bare wire? (But note that this can be totally OK if the box is metallic and wired with certain kinds of metal conduit). Have you opened up the service panel and find there is no ground wire? I don't recommend opening either box if you are not comfortable doing so as you will be exposed to a shock hazard.

Comment: @Stanwood thank you for your help. I used a surge protector which has GND indicator. On the outlets in my living room, it doesn't lit up. On the outlets in the bedroom, it does not lit up and everytime I touch my computer I feel the buzz.

Comment: *Oh, dear*.  You shouldn't feel anything tingly - ever - (except in the first instant, that being shuffle-feet-on-carpet "static electricity" which will be the same whether it's a dryer or a doorknob). Problem is, the "feel the electricity" problem is potentially *lethal* and GFCI won't fix it, it will *trip* and shut off power.

Comment: Given that it's a rental I would put it on your management company to fix it. Their handyman or an electrician should be able to diagnose it. I think you've sorted out enough here to justify making that call.

Comment: @Stanwood thanks I have let them aware of this issue. Since it is a large complex, I doubt I am the only unit with the problem. It will be interesting to see if they offer to fix every unit.

Comment: @Harper well, I still don't know why I feel the sensation, but I know it has to do with grounding. I never had this issue in the living room where every outlet is properly grounded.

Comment: @b1gtuna You've confirmed that surge protector's GND indicator lights up on known-good outlets (e.g., at a friend's house, or at work)?

Comment: @mmathis I've confirmed that the surge protector only lights up the warning light in the bedroom (where I experience the sensation), and not the living room.

Comment: I made an update in the post above. In short, I am getting 86 VAC between ground and a terminal. It is a leak..

Comment: Interesting. That's way too much "antenna-ing" to be explained by no ground.  It would be explained by something with a ground fault plugged into the other socket in the pair... or a ground wire which is present, but disconnected/broken near the panel.  Is everything unplugged from the circuit when you did that test?  What did the other sides of the triangle measure out at?  **The taller blade is neutral**, it *should* measure within 1-2 volts of ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 3 prong outlet with no equipment ground(2wire) needs to be protected by a GFCI and the protected outlets need to be labeled with "No equipment ground" to be legal. Since 2014 code you can add a ground wire that goes back to the same panel seperately from the existing cable then they will be grounded in compliance with the latest code. Both of the above methods are code compliant methods of updating your outlets.

Comment: I just posted a photo of my circuit breaker. Can you take a look and see if it is GFCI compliant..?

Comment: None of those are GFCI breakers (in your service panel photo).

Comment: @Stanwood thank you. 3 prong outlet without GFCI - This is illegal, correct?

Comment: As Ed indicated, 3 prong outlet with no equipment ground does not meet current (2017) code and likely does not meet the adopted code in your jurisdiction (which might be 2008 or older, it takes time for cities to move up to newer versions of the NEC). Given the safety implications I'm fairly certain it would not be grandfathered in. You could have an old house with no ground and 2-prong outlets. You can't upgrade to a 3-prong outlet and not bother to provide and actual equipment ground path.

Comment: @Stanwood ok it is a recently renovated apartment complex. I have sent an email to the management but I will most likely to move out sooner than I expected as this is a pretty big red flag...

Comment: There is no grandfathering for switching 2-prong sockets for 3-prong. There was never legal.

Answer (score 2):

3-prong outlets without ground are legal  **if they are GFCI protected**, with "GFCI protected" and "No equipment ground" stickers.

### About GFCI

GFCI provides a "zone of protection". Let me explain.

Electricity moves on wires.  It flows in *loops* so there must be two wires - out and back again.  (ground is not used normally).

A GFCI module monitors the two normal wires.  It measures all the power "going out" and make sure all of it "comes back again".  Like a playground monitor making sure if 44 kids go to the playground, 44 kids come back.

*A mis-count* means electricity is going somewhere abnormal - possibly shocking someone or risking a fire.  A GFCI will then "trip" or shut off the power.

So --- given the way GFCI works, it casts a "zone of protection" to all wiring downstream of it.  (Any outlets whose two active wires are fed off the GFCI.)

**This means the GFCI can be anywhere**.

You know it's not at the breaker because there are no TEST buttons on them.  However breakers with GFCI cost $40 while $16 buys either a dedicated GFCI module (aka deadface) or a GFCI+receptacle combo device (the normal socket with Test/Reset buttons).

The smart play for the landlord is to fit a $16 device at the first receptacle location on the circuit, apply the stickers and call it good.

So you really need to search the entire unit for any sockets or deadface sockets with the distinctive "Test" and "Reset" button.  If pushing "test" on this device kills power to the sockets you are worried about, then it is protected.

### A thing that zaps you has a problem

A piece of equipment that zaps you has a problem, regardless of whether it is grounded.  Now it's possible the ground has been "saving you" **but it shouldn't need to save you**.

The simple fact is that this leakage which is zapping you is also going to trip a GFCI, and your device won't work and you'll have to fix it or replace it.  So GFCI won't do what you want, it will only provide safety.

At the end of the day, the zappy thing needs to be fixed. If it's a PC, change the power supply, preferably with "not junk".

Comment: Ok I further tested out the "Zaps". I only feel it when I hold the HDMI cable from my monitor on one hand and touch the computer with the other hand. Just using one hand to touch the computer doesn't get me a sensation. Also, I am using EVGA G2, which is one of the best available PSUs. With this in mind, is it possible to exclude any fault on my computer? I am assuming my monitor and the PC have different potential difference (since there is no ground in the outlets)

Comment: @b1gtuna well that makes more sense, as there would need to be a path to complete the circuit.  I hope you don't keep using yourself as a voltmeter without really good life insurance though.  Obviously one device is leaking from hot to chassis and another device is leaking from neutral to chassis. Neither should be happening.  Could be any device with an AC plug.  The proof of the pudding is plug them into a GFCI protected circuit and see if it trips.

Comment: Ok so you believe there is still something wrong with one of my devices? Simply not having a grounded outlet wouldn't cause this sensation with perfectly good electronics?

Comment: @b1gtuna  No.  In the old days there were no grounds, and stuff didn't zap you unless it was broke.  I suspect it's not only one device but two.

Comment: that makes sense. ty!

Comment: It could be the outlet is mis wired or a bootleg ground that is causing the problem.

Comment: @EdBeal if the devices are properly insulated that wouldn't matter... hot/neutral reverse is a possibility, her power strip would report good ground if it was bootlegged.

Comment: I just made an update above. In short, my DMM is reading 86 VAC, and not 124VAC. How can I further debug this issue?

Comment: @AdamLee thinking further about this issue, I wonder if you have a problem called an "islanded ground".  That's where this socket's ground wires connect to other sockets or devices, but this subnetwork of ground wires *does not connect back to the panel and grounding electrode*.  If any device on the island has a ground fault, it lifts the islanded ground toward 120V (since there is nowhere else to go) and spreads the shock Voltage everywhere on the island that is supposed to be grounded. Awesome!